# Spring `RestController` from `AbstractController` in TeamCity

Tags: java, spring, rest, teamcity, spring-restcontroller

The TeamCity plugin API allows adding controllers by extending their `BaseController`, which is a thin wrapper around Spring's `AbstractController`.

When I extend `BaseController` I can inject beans into the constructor in usual Spring manner. This is managed by a beans definition file like standard spring.,

To provide a Controller I must extend `BaseController`, override 
`public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`, and add the controller to the beans definition. I register a URL route as part of constructor initialisation.

That's about all the extension points available to me for Controller.

I was hoping to be able to write small framework that would allow me to annotate my classes with `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping`, etc.

What I think I need to do is:

- Wire up an annotation processor to find my controllers and their methods.
- Build some sort of mapper which maps `@RequestMapping` annotated methods to routes
- Wire up some content handlers, eg serialising/unserialising for JSON and XML
- Dispatch incoming requests to the appropriate method inside my handleRequest method

Most of the above has already been written in Spring and Jersey, and I am wondering where I start researching that.

What classes provide the above functionality?
I've tried a few things to try and instantiate MVC, but it seems to break when `ApplicationContext` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Not a `TeamCity` user. However I'll give my two cents, hoping for the best.
Being that you can register `Spring Bean`(s), why not trying out `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner`?

If you have access somehow to a Spring lifecycle hook, an initialization one, or if you are able to register a `Configuration` class, you can create a `Bean` of type `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. I'll give you a Java example, but you should be able to translate it to XML pretty quickly.

```
@Bean
public BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
            if (beanFactory instanceof BeanDefinitionRegistry) {
                try {
                    final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
                    final ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(registry);
                    scanner.setResourceLoader(applicationContext);
                    scanner.scan("your.base.package");
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    // Handle
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` will register all classes with Spring stereotype annotations.
You can also make a class implement the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` interface directly.